# Riemann-Lebesgue lemma application

Tags: real-analysis

This is problem 42c from chapter 19  from Spivak-Calculus 3rd edition

I need to prove that $$ \lim_{x \to \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x+\frac{1}{2})t\left[\dfrac{2}{t}-\dfrac{1}{\sin\dfrac{t}{2}}\right] dt=0$$
So far i have established that the expression within the brackets is bounded on $[0,\pi]$,
since $$\lim_{t \to 0^+}\dfrac{2}{t}-\dfrac{1}{\sin\dfrac{t}{2}}=0$$which can be shown with a few applications of l´Hospitals rule.

Now the last part of the problem is what has stumped me, the hint in the book suggest that the Reimann-Lebesgue lemma: If $f$ is a integrable function on $[a,b]$ then $$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{a}^{b}\sin(xt)f(t)dt=0$$ can be used to prove the rest. But, I do not see how the limits can be made equal i.e how to transform $\lim_{x \to \pi}$ into $\lim_{u \to \infty}$.
Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: It [seems](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(sin((Pi%2B1%2F2)*t)*(2%2Ft-1%2Fsin(t%2F2)),(t,0,Pi))) the integral is not $0$, maybe there is a typo ?

Comment: Seems like it, every other copy i could find had the same limit. Thank you for your answer!